# Mysql set the password for user

Tags: mysql

When I type `show grants for user` in mysql

Then the sytem showed:

```
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*1E80DD016234830553A761E48526725559582391' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydatabase`.`mytable` TO 'user'@'%'
```

So I typed

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'user'@'%' identified by 'passwd';
```

Then the systemed showed

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*EC75E3374932E7506AB7858A3B026E93FB8ED3DF'                                                                          
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydatabase`.`mytable` TO 'user'@'%'
```

Why I set the password for `user` but there are two phenomenom:

1. the hash code changed but my `passwd` secret didn't show in the table.
2. `mysql -u user` it can log in to the server but `mysql -u user -p` then showed access denied?

Comment: do you flush privileges after doing this?

Comment: @ZiTAL YOu don't need to do that after using the `GRANT` command. Only if you modify the tables directly.

Comment: You set the password to the literal string `passwd`.